# Google Sheets Pivot Table calculating average incorrectly because of blank values

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet with user's feedback and some people left some responses blank. I am using a pivot table to calculate the average but because there are blank values, the pivot table is giving "#DIV/0!". How can I tell the pivot table to ignore empty values so I can have the correct average?

[Google Sheet Example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ndFxiCCd39u5Cb2BkGqdXH5hwcb8C2weYmlYVAZCFV0/edit#gid=839925445)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your Pivot Table range set to `'car survey'!A1:E5`. It should be `'car survey'!A1:E7`. As long as there is at least one non-blank entry per group then the average will return a valid result.

Comment: Hi @Jos Woolley, I have updated the sheet based on your answer and I am still having the same issue unfortunately.  Please refresh the Google Sheet Example. Thanks.

Comment: But for Toyota Prius there is only one entry, which is blank, so what would you expect the average to be for Toyota Prius?

Comment: Woodley I am trying to create a dynamic chart based on the pivot table which will show the avg of "Toyota New and Recurring Buyer", "Toyota First time Buyer", and "Toyota Recurring Buyer" as you can see starting on cell P3. I'm trying to figure out how to tell the pivot table to calculate the average of all Toyota but ignore blank.

Comment: My surname is 'Woolley', not 'Woodley'. And I was talking specifically about 'Toyota Prius', which is currently returning #DIV/0! in your Pivot Table, because 'Toyota Prius' only has one entry in the source data, and it is blank. I wanted to know what you think the result should be for the average of one blank entry.

Comment: My apologies. I understand "Toyota Prius" will return #DIV/0! but I'm trying to figure a way for the pivot table starting in Column P to calculate average for other "Toyota" and not return #DIV/0.

Comment: If you're wishing to use formulas instead, then you may as well do away with your Pivot Tables. In any case, taking an average of your Pivot Table values is equivalent to averaging an already existing average, which doesn't make sense. You should simply interrogate the original dataset with formulas, e.g. `=AVERAGEIF('car survey'!C:C, "Toyota*", 'car survey'!D:D)`.

Comment: Noted. Greatly applicate it.